# Unit Testing in C++ using visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I have given a task to learn unit testing in C++ using visual studio. I have followed [this](http://codeketchup.blogspot.com/2012/12/unit-test-for-unmanaged-c-in-visual.html) tutorial and have added three projects in my solution (main, lib, and test project). I am almost done with this article. But I have some confusions that what functionality performed by static library that I have added here in lib project? And how all these three projects (main, lib and test) in one solution work together to perform unit testing? I want exact and brief answer.

Suggest me some tutorial links related to this as well. Thank you

Comment: I don't really get what exactly you want to know. What are you trying to do? What do you expect and how does this differ from what you get?